# CentOS CPU load and CPU Freq

Tags: linux, centos, central-processing-unit, cpu-usage

I have some Dual Xeon (X5650 @ 2.67GHz) server, with 72GB of RAM and HT disabled, but I have a problem.

I host srcds servers (game servers) and they are really CPU intensive. The CPU usage is usually over 50% but CPU load is 0.05~0.30 (even if I run 10 servers, each server using 1 core 100%, it will stay 0.05~0.30).

The problem is that the CPU do not ramp up, it just stays at 1.5Ghz forever as there is no load registered by the system, when actually there is. As the game servers load increase it start lagging and dropping frames becuse of the low CPU freq.

I did some benchmarks on the server, and the CPU load and frequency did rump up to ~3Ghz as it should, so I don't think its a server problem.

I used to use Ubuntu, and the CPU load was ok, but I dont want to reformat the server and set everything up again.

I there anything I can do to make CentOS display the right load and ramp up the CPU frequency as it should?

Comment: I'm confused. You are having this problem with a server, but then you say you did benchmarks on the server and it did ramp up as expected and that you don't think it is a server problem. Can you clarify?

Comment: I don't think its related to the server itself, but related to the OS.

Comment: Which version of CentOS?

Comment: CentOS release 6.7 (Final) 64bit

Comment: what motherboard?

Comment: The motherboard is Dell 2Y41P N582M. The server is a PowerEdge M610. BIOS version 6.0.7.

Comment: Tweak the power saving profiles in the BIOS to performance or turn off power saving?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check if you've a CPU govenor enabled.

Check that your actual frequency matches up with the capabilities of the CPU.

> grep -E '^model name|^cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo

If it doesn't match up try to kill the cpuspeed service and see if things levels out properly.

> service cpuspeed stop

Alternatively run the following bash-script:

```
for CPUFREQ in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
        do
                [ -f $CPUFREQ ] || continue
                echo -n performance > $CPUFREQ
        done
```